# git pull error Could't find remote ref master

Tags: git

I created a bare git repository with http access on my server. On client i use:

```
git init
git clone <URL>
touch 2.txt
git commit
git remote add origin <URL>
git push origin master
```

All these commands work fine. Then i want to see whether my repository has "2.txt"
I from other machine i use:

```
git init
git clone <URL>
git remote add origin <URL>
git pull origin master
```

and i got:

```
Could't find remote ref master
Unexpected end of command stream
```

I tried other variant:

```
git pull
```

and i got:

```
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'master' 
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched
```

I think, the problem is that i havent any branches on server. I tried to create branch master on server, but nothing (mb coz that is bare repository)
I used that guide to create http access to the repository:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.txt
I completed steps 1-2 and then started to do it without guide. 
I think i missed something and my initial push is wrong, coz it doesnt create a branch, but i dont know, what to do with it.
I am new with git, and i really hope u will help me.

Comment: You don't need to run `git init` before `git clone`. That will almost certainly get you into trouble in fact, because you'll get "nested repositories".

Comment: I am quite sure that your `git push origin master` fails.

Comment: `git clone <URL>` alone is enough. It will initialize, add remote as well as pull from remote.

Comment: If you clone a repository, it automatically assigns that to be `origin` in the new one so you don't need the `add remote` command either. I'm not sure it would cause this problem though.

Comment: You're not telling us everything. Your first block of code is not supposed to *work fine*. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

From the 2nd machine you just run the following command

`git clone "your git-URL"`

You'll have the git repo with 2.txt file.

Comment: Nope. According to the OP's first block of commands, `2.txt` was never staged, and therefore never found its way into any commit.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, your remote does not have a branch 'master'

When you start working on a new repo make sure that you have a master branch. You can do this with

```
git checkout -b master
```

Do this in your existing repo and push again. Then it should clone as expected.

Comment: No need for this command. In a brand new repo, the `master` branch will be created with the first commit.

Comment: You must have been doing something wrong. You never need to create a `master` branch explicitly after initializing a repo; it automatically comes into being when the first commit is created. Try it for yourself: `mkdir testgit || cd testgit`, `git init`, `touch test.txt`, `git add test.txt`, `git commit -m "initial commit"`, `git branch`.

Comment: I know that this isn't the expected behaviour and it happened when I inited the (bare) repo on the server, cloned it (brings a message with sth. like "it appears you have cloned an empty repo") on my local machine and pushed to it. When I forget to checkout a master first I always get the same message as the OP. Anyway - sth. went wrong and checking out the master explicitly and pushing it solved this for me.